# How can I insert a lone dot on a line using ed's "insert" command?

Tags: ed

How may I insert a lone dot on a line with the `ed` editor? Normally, a dot on a line by itself ends the insertion; can it somehow be escaped?

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot insert a period on a line by itself, because that's `ed`'s instruction to stop inserting text; see one of the early [ed man pages](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/man12.pdf) (page 7):

> Input mode is left by typing a period (.) alone at the beginning of a line.

You can work around it by not entering a period by itself; for example: <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by `s/^ //`. You could use any other character than Space as the token, as long as you pair it in the subsequent `s//` command.

A period cannot be inserted by itself; when appending, changing, or inserting a line, `ed` ends up calling the `append_lines` function; that function, in *buffer.c*, reads input delimited by a newline (via `get_stdin_line`). As part of that, it checks to see if a period is the only thing (besides the trailing newline) in the result; below, "ibufpp" is the pointer to the inputted text and "size" is the length of that buffer:

```
if( size == 2 && **ibufpp == '.' ) { *ibufpp += size; return true; }
```

You can download compressed tar bundles at: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/ed/ or view [Debian's upstream page for ed](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ed) or [OpenBSD's page for ed](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/bin/ed/main.c#L1046) where the corresponding code is in [main.c](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/bin/ed/main.c#L1046).

Another option, discovered in an [ed(1) Conference twitter post](https://twitter.com/ed1conf/status/1133184171373989888), is to enter any *other* single character, then replace that character with a period:

1. <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. `s/./.`

Comment: So just to be clear, there's no way to actually enter it *in insert mode* ?

Comment: Depending on your keyboard layout, you could pick for a token any key that's quick to type adjacent to both period and `/`, then use an unanchored `s/k//` (with `k` as an example), if you find that faster to type.

Comment: @Brennan, see the recent edit

Comment: @JeffSchaller https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ed/blob/upstream/1.15/buffer.c#L127

Comment: Thank you, A.B -- I've incorporated that into the most recent edit.

Comment: On OpenBSD (which does not use GNU `ed` by default), the relevant code is line 1046 in `main.c`: https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/bin/ed/main.c#L1046  Other BSDs are likely using this variant of `ed` too.

Comment: So, just to be clear, there's no way to do it with just the "insert" command.

Comment: Thank you to Kusalananda - I've incorporated that link. Also thanks to ilkkachu for the nudge to have a direct answer (at the top).

Comment: Because, there _could be_. In SMTP, a line with just a dot ends the data part of the message, but you can still send an email with a single dot on a line by itself: it gets sent as `..` on the protocol level (and any other lines that start with a dot get that dot removed).

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, edited to remove reference to "insert mode" terminology which I had (I guess wrongly) assumed was similar between ed and vi.

Comment: @BrennanVincent My apologies. There are in fact references to "input mode" even in [the POSIX specification for `ed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ed.html). I was honestly not aware that this was called "input mode", and I was obviously wrong in saying there was no such thing. `ed` (a line editor) being very different from `vi` (a screen editor), the modes "feel" very different though. The current phasing in the question does not feel odd or wrong at all, but feel free to change back if you wish.